# How to save the canvas text/image in gallery

Tags: android, html, cordova, canvas

I have develop the canvas image to store the gallery.I have add the plugins from

```
**cordova plugin add https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin.git**
```

I have write the signature in the device, But unable to save in the gallery.

**Here following code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />    

             <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>         
             <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>       
             <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.34982.js"></script> 
             <script type="text/javascript" src="js/signatureCapture.js"></script>           
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />                   
             <script type="text/javascript">
             var sigCapture;
             $(document).ready(function(e) 
            {       
                    sigCapture = new SignatureCapture( "signature" );
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);         
                    function onDeviceReady()  
                    {
                        window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
                                function(msg){
                                    console.log("Save =========>"+msg);
                                },
                                function(err){
                                    console.log("Error =====>"+err);
                                },
                                document.getElementById('signature')
                            );
                    }
                    $("#submit").click( onSubmitClick );
                    $("#cancel").click( onCancelClick );
                });
             function onSubmitClick(event ) { }
             function onCancelClick( event ) {
                 sigCapture.clear();
                }

             </script>
        </head>
        <body>

       <h2>SIGNATURE</h2>
        <div id="canvasContainer"  >
            <canvas id="signature" />
        </div>

       <button data-role="button" id="submit" data-theme="b">Save</button>
        <button data-role="button" id="cancel" data-theme="b">Cancel</button>       



        </body>
    </html>
```

**Error console :**

The image could not be decoded at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:55

please some one can help me how to save the canvas text in image gallery.

Comment: You seem to be doing good. Maybe you are missing some canvas initialisation : set width, height...

Comment: I have specified the width, height and etc in the CSS file.I have included can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **toDataURL** method to convert your canvas to URL then you can download it using this URL, something like that:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<button id="downloadImageButton">Download Image</button>

<script>
  const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
        downloadImageButton = document.getElementById('downloadImageButton');

  downloadImageButton.addEventListener('click', downloadCanvasAsImage);

 function downloadCanvasAsImage() {
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'myCanvasAsImage.png';
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    link.click();
 }

</script>
```